# Youtube content does not appear while using proxy?

Tags: proxy

I am from IRAN, As you know YouTube is filtered here. We use proxies to bypass filtering but unfortunately after opening YouTube's site the content(videos) won't display. I have tried using last version of Flash so that cannot be the cause.

Is it true that usually proxies have problem showing some content like videos? If it is, how come one proxy works fine for one person and has issue for another one? Could it be due to a server problem like not supporting Flash or ...?

Do you know what is the reason and how to overcome this issue?

By the way when we could use VPN we did not have such a problem at all.

Comment: In my test. If I use proxy globally then it is fine. But if I use proxy only for youtube.com then the problem appear.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that YT does not only rely on your IP to determine if you can access content which is potentially blocked. There are other things YT may factor in for evaluation like your browser/OS language, cookies, settings/data from a google account you are logged into etc.

Your biggest problem however is that flash is able to access certain settings on your system so in most cases the flash plugin itself will be responsible for determining where you are located. Flash also has the possibility to bypass your proxy and to reveal your public IP address.

You might want to give the [HTML5 Version of Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/html5) a try as you can fully disable flash then.